# How can i include two same classes in single css file?

Tags: html, css

Now i am having two CSS files. if i want to include them in single CSS file without making changes then how can i include them.

File 1:

```
.class1{ background-color: red;}
```

File 2:

```
.class1{ background-color: blue;}
```

Comment: Why would you want to keep these css definition in a single css file. Since the class name is same, the one definition among the two which you will place above will be overridden by below one.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if u give the same class name with different colors it will be overwritten according to your question

```
      File 1:    .class1{ background-color: red;}
file 2: .class1{ background-color: blue;}
```

it will be overwritten so u have to specify diffrent class name or add one new class and overwrite class1 style like

```
.class2{ background-color: green !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the classes as they stand, you can't do what you're trying to do. The two properties collide, which means that whichever file is included later in the HTML file (in the `link` tags) will be the one that takes effect.

If you put them both in the same CSS file, the one that was declared later in the file will be the 'dominant' one and will take affect (I can't test this right now, so if someone could let me know in the comments if this is correct that'd be great).

If you want to have two different background colours, simply use two different classes - I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve by using the one class and defining it twice, with two different definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you add a second css file the class will still get overwritten. Probably best to target more specifically if using the same class name. See below

```
.block-one .class1 {}
.block-two .class1 {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include them in one file , but just one of them will make effect.what if you must to do this, you'd better to add a prefix property to specify them.